# About SMS with uwp app windows phone 10

Tags: c#, sms, uwp

I used this Code on windows 10 but only I receive a Blank page... I add the capabilities.. "restricted capabilities" But I don't know if this Blank page is correct or not?

This is my code similar

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private MainPage rootPage;
    public SmsDevice2 device;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        mensaje();
    }


    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //rootPage = MainPage.Current;
    }

    public async void mensaje()
    {
        device = SmsDevice2.GetDefault();
        SmsTextMessage2 msg = new SmsTextMessage2();
        msg.To = "+12345678";
        msg.Body = "Test";

        SmsSendMessageResult result = 
          await device.SendMessageAndGetResultAsync(msg);
     }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "receive a Blank page"? You receive none message? The code you posted is for sms sending, I didn't find any problem there in this code.

Comment: hello friend i cant to send or recive any sms.. I dont understand what is wrong.. when I execute only display a  blank page and don't send sms

Comment: Since your code has no problem here, and you have already added the capabilities, I can only recommend you to download the official [SMS send and receive sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive), see how the official sample get it fire.